# Why does a PB-02 ignore a "AT+NAME=abc123"?

Tags: uart, bluetooth, at-commands

When I connect to a [PB-02](https://docs.ai-thinker.com/en/blue_tooth_pb#resource_summary) via UART(8data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit) it does not execute all AT commands.
These work fine:

1. `AT\r\n` results in `AT\r\n\nOK\r\n`
2. `AT+RST\r\n` results in :

   ```
   AT+RST
   \r\n\n
   OK\r\n
   all driver init\n
   ###################\r\n
   \r\n
   arch:phy6212\n
   company:Ai-Thinker|B&T\n
   MAC:94 C9 60 88 DC DB\n
   sdk_version:release/V2.1.0\n
   firmware_version:release/V1008 \r\n
   compile_time:Sep  3 2021 15:41:57\n\r\n
   ready\n
   ###################\n
   ```
3. ATE0 and ATE1 work as expected...
4. It also dumps messages like `CON OK\r\n` and `DISCONNECT OK\r\n`, when I connect with a Test App...

but:

1. `AT+NAME?\r\n` and `AT+NAME=WhiteTulip\r\n` do not work. There is just the echo. But no `OK` and no name change.

Why is that?

How can I change its name and add parity bits, without flashing new firmware?

Comment: To help get an answer, can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/701031/edit) the question and include a link to the documentation for the ``PB-02``. I'm guessing it is some sort of modem.

Comment: They call it "bluetooth module". On the UART side it speaks "AT". And on the airside it speaks Bluetooth BLE 5.0. But: The PDF "PB-01/02 Tmall Genie docking at instruction set" and the PDF "PB-01/02 Bluetooth passthrough (non mesh) at instruction set" describes AT commands, that the PB-02 does not understand.

Comment: Using google translate to convert the documentation from Chinese (Simplified) to English, I can't see any error in the AT commands you are using for ``AT+NAME?`` and ``AT+NAME=WhiteTulip``. The translated document does say ``Changing the Bluetooth device name requires restarting to take effect. The maximum length is 20 bytes.``. Have you tried restarting the PB-02 after attempting to change the name?

Comment: @ChesterGillon it does not even reply "OK", although that PDF says, it should do. I just did that ``AT+NAME=WhiteTulip`` and then a power cycle, but it still says its name is "ai-Thinker"...

Comment: Given the firmware doesn't reply to the ``AT+NAME``, you might have to contact Ai-Thinker Technology support to ask why the firmware doesn't even reply "OK".

Comment: @ChesterGillon seems like my PB-02 has a special firmware. I found a PDF in the meantime with hefty google-ing, that talks about ``AT+BLENAME...``. :) But I also told Ai-Thinker via email, that my PB-02 behaves funny. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [PDF](https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/pb%E7%B3%BB%E5%88%97%E6%A8%A1%E7%BB%84%E9%80%9A%E7%94%A8at_v1006%E7%89%88%E6%9C%AC%E6%8C%87%E4%BB%A4_v1.1.3.pdf) via Google.
It says that it is "BLENAME" in v1.1.3.

```
AT+BLENAME?<0D>

name:ai-Thinker
OK<0D>
AT+BLENAME=White Tulip<0D>

OK<0D>
```

But: `AT+UARTCFG?` says just `+UARTCFG:115200` (no parity configurable). So I seem to have a special version v1.1.3. So I will use 32bit CRC every few bytes. That should be even better than parity (which is 1bit CRC, IIRC).